# Magento 2 Image URL's missing from table

Tags: magento2

I have a lot of images that I have moved onto the server in pub/media.

However none of them appear when you try and insert them through the Magento admin WYSIWYG editor.

I believe this is because the table media_gallery_asset is blank.

Is there anyway to regenerate this table with all the images that are sat on the server?

Answer (score 0):

If they do not appear in the WYSIWYG editor then its possible you have added them to the wrong directory the images sshould be in ./pub/media/wysiwyg/ also make sure the images have the correct permissions.

Comment: They are all in that directory, I believe all images are added to the media_gallery_asset table in the database since the introduction of adobe stock images. I need all the paths putting in the database some how?